# Bootstrap and AngularJS: form-control-lg changes only input size, not label

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [AngularJS custom text input component](https://plnkr.co/edit/UVQuY6QrqX7qp8ATFyoZ?p=preview):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback"
     ng-class="[$ctrl.sizeClass, {'has-error': $ctrl.isNotValid(), 'has-success': 
     $ctrl.isValid()}]"
>
   <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="{{$ctrl.name}}">
    <span ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>
    <small ng-if="$ctrl.isRequired">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-danger">
        *
      </span>
      <span class="sr-only">
        (field is required)
      </span>
    </small>
   </label>
   <!-- Input which works perfect -->
</div>
```

And I want to add sizing based on [Bootstrap form-group sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes):

```
var sizes = {
  'sm': 'form-group-sm',
  'lg': 'form-group-lg',
};

$ctrl.$onChanges = function (changes) {
  if (changes.size) {
    $ctrl.sizeClass = sizes[$ctrl.size];
  }
}
```

And `input` size changes properly, but `label` size won't change. I am pretty sure I am missing something silly stupid. Would you like to help me? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed some CSS:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group-sm .control-label {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I found it just few seconds ago :) Bootstrap has some weird media query on it, and I will report it as issue on their Github, cause this is quite inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It's because Bootstrap's CSS `media query`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
.form-horizontal .form-group-lg .control-label {
    padding-top: 11px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

And Plunker window is narrower than 768 px (try to resize code panel to test it). I will report it as issue on Bootstrap's Github. Reported: [Sizes for form-horizontal's .control-label on min-width < 768px does not work as expected for .control-label but work for .form-control (visible with with .col-xs-*)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22537).